# API endpoint POST vs GET

Tags: rest, api, api-design, web-api

Help me settle an internal question.

We have an endpoint which we all agree *should* be a GET, because all it's doing is calling a stored proc and returning a set of data.  However, there is a set of filters that we need to pass to the endpoint.  Below is an example of what the filers might look like if all of the filter options are passed:

```
{
    "DistributorCode":"6065",
    "Model":"123-xyz",
    "Serial":"654654065",
    "CurrentSMR":"11350.47",
    "SoldbyDistributor":"",
    "ServiceDistributor":"",
    "LatestSMRDate":"02/12/2020",
    "Coverage":"",
    "Customer":"",
    "CoverageExpirayDate":"",
    "SortBy":{
        "name" :"serial",
        "order":"asc"
    },
    "select":["eh","wt","fc"]
}
```

We could just pass in this json string as a querystring parameter in the GET call, or we could have each of them be their own parameter (although SortBy might get tricky).

But some are concerned that this will make the URL too long, and we will risk running into `max query string length` errors.  So, they want to make the call a POST instead.  If it were a POST call, then it would require both an object in the body and at least one QS param (&code=) which is non-negotiable (it must be there.)

So we have two options (that I can think of):

1. Make it a GET call with a potentially very long URL due to the parameters.

   1a) each filter is its own parameter

   1b) the list of filters is a json string in it's own parameter
2. Make it a POST call that requires both QS parameters and a json object in the Body

Which would you do, and why?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @JonRaynor, thanks but I'm not sure how that applies to my question here. That questions is: `Can I pass a body with a GET call.` That's not what I am asking here.

Comment: If your search parameters can't be accommodated via a query string, go with a post.  I can't predict what the future needs of your application will be.  Certainly a POST will be able to handle more information than a query string.

Comment: @JonRaynor, thanks. After googling the correct thing, I finally found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202257/design-restful-query-api-with-a-long-list-of-query-parameters which pretty much says what you said. It's okay to use POST in a case like this.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers you have 2000 characters for the whole URL. Subtract about 100 for the domainname, path, etc. and there is still plenty of space left for your entire question.

Comment: select000000000000000000000001=eh&select000000000000000000000002=...

Comment: SortBy is easy: `SortBy=-serial,+id`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do a GET with normal parameters. You are nowhere near the limit. You may want to make a little helper function that can take an arbitrary object and turn it into a query string.

The problem with 1b it is hard to debug (just changing a parameter in your web debugger becomes a chore). Also logs will be obscured. You lose out on the ability to filter access log for all instances where parameterx=Y etc.

The problem with 2 is you miss out on handy features like caching etc.

Also GET with body is a horrible hack. Don't do that

Also regarding the array in your example. Query strings support the same parameter multiple times so you can do ?select=eh&select=wt&select=fc

Comment: Thanks! `Also GET with body is a horrible hack. Don't do that` < That was never on the table as an option :)

Comment: I would also recommend not passing fields with no values.  Your example body shows a number of fields with values of "".  I'm assuming you don't want to only see e.g. records where the "Customer" is blank.  You should just send parameters for fields that you are not part of the filter.

Comment: @JimmyJames, yes, you are correct. I just copied and pasted an example showing all possible values.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston One other small recommendation: use ISO-style dates e.g. 2020-02-12.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a POST with a body. You have an unbounded array `"select":["eh","wt","fc"]` which is going to be a pain to serialise as query string parameters and can possibly exceed the URL length restriction.

I would also recommend scrapping your sproc, having a simpler method that returned more objects and moving the filtering to the client.

This will take load off the database and make for a faster UI

Also spell check `CoverageExpirayDate`

Comment: `moving the filtering to the client.... This will take load off the database and make for a faster UI` Except for very tiny tables, that is rarely going to be the case. Server side filtering, with appropriate indexes are going to beat client side filtering in the majority of cases.

Comment: sorry thats just not true. client side is inherently more scale-able and in this case the OP is passing sort parameters for example

Comment: letting the client download 100MB of data so it can display 10 rows is a very inefficient use of database resources. Your database isn't going to scale that way.

Comment: its ineffecient use of bandwidth, its super effecient use of database

Comment: Serializing millions of rows that ends up never being used is not a "super efficient use of database".

Comment: the web backend handles that

Comment: How do you think the data gets from the database server to the web server? I think it's quite clear that you don't know how databases works.

Comment: binary connections.

Comment: binary serialization is serialization, it involves lots of copying, transforming from on-disk to on-wire format, a bloody sequential scan, and the DB server's CPU is very much involved in that. Do you even know how computers work?

Comment: better than you it seems. Look if you dont believe me, test it.

Comment: LOL, Thanks for the trolling. I work with real databases with millions of rows of tables of data that gets updated constantly with sensitive informations. There's no way suggestimh allowing client to download gigabytes of data that's going to expire in three seconds and cause all sorts of sensitive data leakages is gonna fly with anyone. You should learn to use indexes.

Comment: sounds very 90's

Answer (score 2):

In this case, often both possibilities are used:

- Create a GET endpoint passing your query conditions in the query string (like suggestion 1a). You can also pass sort parameters easily in the query string.

You should only pass query parameters that are not empty or which are different from default values.

- If you think that the query string may get too long (even though [there is no specification limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3091523/3271844), servers will usually have a limit), you can create a POST endpoint. You then pass the query and sort conditions in the body, preferably using JSON format.

In your example, the query string should not get too long. So here the GET endpoint is enough.